# Plane lock depending on the orthographic view you're using?

Tags: transforms, snapping, axis

Quick Ask: Does Blender offer an adaptive axis/plane lock in orthographic views, similar to Rhino's 'project snapping to CPlane'?

Plane locking is using a command like SHIFT-Z to restrict movement to the X/Y axis. This is fine but I'm wondering if it's possible to turn this on automatically depending on the orthographic view you're currently using. For example, if you're in the top-down view, the transforms and snaps you do should not be in the Z axis.

Specifically, I'm wondering about snapping from point to point.

I'm aware of being able to click the lock icon in the properties panel in Blender which disables transform in an axis, but this is not what I'm asking about.

I do a lot of architectural modeling in Rhino, and it's a simple setting you can turn on the the options. The option is called ~"project snapping to CPlane in orthographic view".

Is this, "projected movement / snapping" possible in Blender? Thank you

Comment: Not that I know... and if you are moving vertices in _Edit Mode_ for example you have to use `Shift`+`Z` (or `Shift`+`X` or `Shift`+`Y`, depending on which axis you want to lock) because there are no lock icons to click. Or if you don't want to use `Shift`+ axis you can enable the transform gizmos and use the small square to lock that axis while moving.

Comment: This is already automatic for moves without snapping.If you use 'G', 'R' os 'S' in any ortho view, without any explicit constraint, transforms will be in view-plane. You can align an ortho view to any face  with selection > Shift - Numpad 7. For snapping, you can  set Transform Orientation to 'View'. In which case the constraint will always be Shift-Z.